# Headphone mic not working with laptop 3.5mm port

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, microphone

I have sennheiser hd4.40 wireless headphone. I also got a cable with headphone having 2.5mm pin(attached to headphone) to 3.5mm pin(attached to mobile phone).

Problem is that when i connect 3.5mm pin to my mobile phone headphone jack, in call i am able to use mic and headphone both at same time but:

1. When i connect the 3.5mm pin to 3.5mm jack for mic on my laptop, i am not able to use the mic.(my laptop has separate 3.5mm mic and 3.5mm headphone jack)
2. When i connect to 3.5mm jack for headphone, only headphone is working with laptop not mic.

Please do not suggest why I am not using Bluetooth because it is a separate problem.

I am missing something or maybe this may be limitation or something else. Help me on this. :-(

Comment: Your phone uses a TRRS socket. Your laptop uses a separate TRS and TS socket. You need a splitter, e.g. https://www.startech.com/au/Cables/Audio-Video/Audio-Cables/35mm-4-Position-to-2x-3-Position-35mm-Headset-Splitter-Adapter-F-M~MUYHSFMM (similar can be found cheap on Amazon, eBay)

Comment: @Bob i am also thinking about the same splitter but i am curious whether it will work or not. As per me, when i connect 3.5mm to 3.5mm mic, at-least mic should work. What you say?

Comment: There's [at least two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#TRRS_standards) different TRRS pinouts commonly used - which switch the mic and ground pins when compared to each other. You can see where compatibility issues arise. There's also no guarantee that any given TRRS connector will work in a TRS or TS socket. "3.5mm socket" is very vague. "3.5mm TRRS socket" is slightly less vague. "3.5mm TRRS socket with CTIA pinout" is precise, but different from "3.5mm TRRS socket with OMTP pinout".

Comment: Just as there's no guarantee that "3.5mm TRRS plug with CTIA pinout" is going to work in "3.5mm TS socket with mic/ground pinout". See also: http://www.mgraves.org/2014/08/wired-headsets-a-tutorial-on-connectors-cables-pinouts/

Comment: @Bob sorry don't know these terminologies(TRRS, TS socket, CTIA pinout). :-(

Comment: Read the linked page: http://www.mgraves.org/2014/08/wired-headsets-a-tutorial-on-connectors-cables-pinouts/ Basically, your different ports assign different parts of the connector to "mic" and "ground", even though they look the same on the surface. So you need an adapter.

Comment: Is this headset Android or apple compatible?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes. I also mentioned it is working fine with my android phone(oneplus 5).

Comment: @Bob thanks for such an informative article. I ordered https://www.amazon.in/UNMCORE-Plated-Headphone-Earphone-Splitter/dp/B0711Z7X7C/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&qid=1507183443&sr=8-12&keywords=3.5mm+female and hoping it will work.