# Microphone don't work on PC (electrelet condenser mic with 3.5 mm jack, requiring power)

Tags: audio, microphone

I have an **Olympus ME51S microphone** bought several years ago that still work when I plug it in an Olympus voice recorder.  It is a  external microphone of type condenser /electrelet that allows to record in stereo.  From other website, I see that this microphone can work with various equipment like a Camcorder or GoPro.

[image: Picture of the ME51S microphone]

Having said that, my problem is that I would like to use it with my desktop computer. But when I plug this microphone in my PC using the 3.5mm audio jack for microphone it does not work (it will not record any sound). I have read on various websites that the problem is that this microphone requires power and that the jack of a computer will typically not provide power.

The voice recorder is providing that power. But how can I ensure that the computer will provide the power to the microphone so that I could use that microphone on my computer to record stereo audio?

Here is the **detailed specifications of the ME51S microphone**:
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/114474/Olympus-Me-51s.html

If it is relevant, I use a ASUS laptop with Window 10, and i plug the microphone to a USB adapter that provides the 3.5 mm input jack. But, I previously tried it on another computer a few years ago and had the same problem. And other people have reported a similar problem on Amazon and other websites but after searching for more than an hour, I did not find any solution.

I know that there exist microphones that require phantom power, but they generally have a XLR jack rather than a 3.5 mm jack, so it does not help me to solve the problem. Thus, would there be an adapter that I could buy to use my  microphone on a computer?

**EDIT**: I also have the same problem with a mono Olympus ME12 microphone.

The USB adapter is CE-LINK audio adapter bought from a Chinese website (https://item.jd.com/3085089.html ):

[image: CE LINK adapter]

The adapter works fine for listening to audio, and according to the website works for windows. But as suggested in one of the answer, it is likely mono.

EDIT2: Here is a picture of how I plugged it in the computer. I of course tried both input jacks of the USB adapter to rule out that I would plug it in the wrong one. The adapter is also working to listen to music with headphones (the output). So I assume that the adapter is not defective.

[image]

EDIT 3
I also tried plugging it in a desktop computer at the office using the audio in port. It also does not work.

Comment: Related: https://www.gearslutz.com/board/remote-possibilities-in-acoustic-music-and-location-recording/555761-plug-power-not-phantom-xlr-adapters.html

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using? USB should have no problem providing plug-in-power. Since the specs only mention plug-in-power, phantom power shouldn't be the issue. Since this is a stereo mic, it needs a compatible input jack. Based on the [rings](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Jackplug-wiring.svg/383px-Jackplug-wiring.svg.png), the input should have both left and right power/signal

Comment: I edited the answer to add the details about the adapter. It is a kind of USB audio card type of adapter. Bought it from Chinese website, and not much information about the specification.

Comment: I didn't see any useful details in the specs either. Does your laptop have a combo jack or is there one just for mic input? EDIT: Just noticed from the picture that the jack(s) on the adapter looks like a combo jack, allowing both mic and headphones. That may be the problem.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I can plug heaphones in both jack of the USB adapter and I can hear the sound. So it is some combo jacks.   The reason why I bought this adapter is that my laptop only has an audio output. There is no audio input.  Besides, the laptop integrated microphone is not good.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read in Amazon and Newegg reviews/questions, it is possible to use this mic with PC's.

Copied from my comment:

> USB should have no problem providing plug-in-power. Since the specs only mention plug-in-power, phantom power shouldn't be the issue. Since this is a stereo mic, it needs a compatible input jack. Based on the rings, the input should have both left and right power/signal.

I couldn't find detailed specs on the adapter you listed. Based on the rings, your mic is a TRS mic. If your laptop has a combo jack, you could use a [splitter like this one](https://smile.amazon.com/UGREEN-Headsets-Separate-Headphone-Microphone/dp/B073ZCWDZY/). It only supports TRS, and not TS/TRRS.

[image: TRS]

I found a couple of related questions.

1. [Headphone mic not working with laptop 3.5mm port](https://superuser.com/questions/1256026/headphone-mic-not-working-with-laptop-3-5mm-port)
2. https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/40656/plug-in-power-microphone-to-pc

Unfortunately the OP in 1 never responded if it worked or not, but in 2 they mentioned

> Electret condenser microphones will deliver output even without plugin power. Really, really bad, low-gain high-noise output.

You should be able to pick up something to confirm it is working.

Comment: Apart from the stereo-to-mono issue, no typical onboard or USB audio device will provide the power the manufacturer says it's needed.

Comment: Thanks!  So I think that a TRS to TTRS converter like this one would also work then?  https://item.jd.com/27825645139.html   I can buy one to try it. But yes, maybe it would still record in mono though, as pointed out by Gabriela, and hope power is not an issue.

Comment: I think @GabrielaGarcia 's concerns about the power are valid. I wouldn't want you to buy something only to not have it work. I found a couple related questions I'll edit into the post. EDIT: But yes, that converter is like the splitter without the headphone part so it should work

Comment: Ok, I see, yes. Thanks for the comments. I think you bring some good ideas and help clarify the problem, and this will help to move toward a possible solution.  If there is something that I can buy even if it not 100% sure to work, I can buy it since I can refund it through my work.. But I will not order right away something because of the above concerns and see if there is other solutions;-) I keep reading what you find.

Comment: I increase the level (DB) to the max in the audio settings of the microphone in windows. When I plug the microphone in the USB adapter, I hear a click sound from the microphone. But besides that i just hear noise.  I talk on the microphone but cannot record anything but noise.  But the microphone is not broken. It works in my Olympus voice recorder to record my voice.

Comment: Tomorrow, I can also try it on other computers again.

Comment: I tried on another computer at the office and it also just produce noise.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the "Performance precautions" in the same [manual you linked in the question](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/114474/Olympus-Me-51s.html).

Namely:

- Do not use this microphone with any recorder that cannot supply power to an external microphone.

There's no computer hardware, internal or external (USB, etc.), designed to do this.

And also you would need the pictured adapter cable because MIC jacks in PCs are typically mono so, as stated in the manual, without it only the left channel would be recorded and that negates the point of having a stereo microphone. It could work in LINE-IN jacks that are typically stereo but, again, not powered, and intended for a preamplified signal (it has no "boost" features).

**Conclusion:**

Your microphone is designed to work with specific devices with characteristics typically not found in consumer grade PCs -- and especially not in notebooks -- and other consumer grade electronics.

Comment: Indeed, only recording in mono is not very interesting and thanks for this observation. However, I also have  another Olympus microphone that is mono and have the same problem. If I could find a solution, it could be used for that mono microphone at least. But I think you are right and I made a mistake by buying hardware that seems to be very specialized and perhaps not so standard.  Let's see if others have some solutions...

Comment: It seems people have successfully used this mic with PC's (based on reviews from Amazon/Newegg). The cable included is only an extension, not an adapter. I'm guessing it likely has to do with the USB to 3.5mm input adapater OP mentioned he's using.

Comment: @MC10 I don't know about those reviews. It's possible they have non-standard equipment or an amplifier in-between. And the cable is a "stereo-to-mono" adapter, not just an extension

Comment: This is completely incorrect. The pink 3.5mm mic input jack on all PCs is a TRS connector which supplies +5V on the ring. It's been that way forever. And SoudBlaster cards had +5V mic jacks on them before it was standard to have onboard sound.